# How to use GLKit within the Xcode OS X Swift Playground?

Tags: xcode, glkit, swift, swift-playground

I'm trying to use GLKit within the Xcode 6 OS X Swift Playground but the

```
import GLKit
```

doesn't seem enough to make Playground recognize GLKView. Any ideas?

```
import Cocoa
import GLKit
import OpenGL

let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 300)
class TriangleView: GLKView { // ERROR: Use of undeclared type 'GLKView'
    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 1.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create iOS project and add new .playground file inside that project. Then you can import GLkit, I also had to import OpenGLES instead of OpenGL.

```
import UIKit

import GLKit
import OpenGLES

let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 300)
class TriangleView: GLKView { // ERROR: Use of undeclared type 'GLKView'
    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: CGRect) {
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 1.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm using an OSX Playground which can't import OpenGLES. The iOS Playground doesn't seem to have the XCPlayground facility.

Comment: Then as you suggested NSOpenGLView instead of GLKView

Comment: @Waruna do you know how to enable live views in xcode ?

Comment: @LenaBru What you mean by live views? Are you talking about Xcode6 playground?

Comment: @Waruna the manual of swift says that i can write custom views, and have them rendered in xcode interface builder, but the xcode keeps complaining that it cant render the views, because the bundle isnt executable

Comment: @LeanBru I think this should go has a separate question. if possible post a new question with you code. Then we can see whats going wrong.

Comment: Just out of interest @Waruna, are you able to access GLKit Math types by importing GLKit? I don't seem to be able to get at them.

Comment: @ephemera looks like, it is. GLKit.GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90) gives me 1.571

Answer (score 3):

There is no GLKView in OS X! From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/osx_technology_overview/MigratingFromCocoaTouch/MigratingFromCocoaTouch.html):

> In OS X, NSOpenGLView class subsumes the GLKView and GLKViewController
>   classes in iOS.